# Batch file: Conditional copy between two folders

Tags: batch-file

I need your help. I am looking for a batch file to do a specific operation with a check. Let me explain the situation :

I have 2 folders (C:\Folder1 and C:\Folder2)
I wonder if it might be possible to have a batch file that  for each *.TXT file that is placed into Folder1  places a copy of that file to Folder 2 (after comparing the 2 folders and making sure that this file is not present in Folder2).

Is it possible to also have a counter as when another TXT file is put in to Folder1 it should only copy that File to Folder2 (not all the previous txt files already added into A).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  It already will only copy changed files and has a lot of options to control what it will copy.  It is built in in Vista+ and can be downloaded for Windows XP/Server 2003 in the [Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).

Answer (score 3):

This will copy any txt file that does not exist in `c:\folder2` but does exist in the **current** folder to `c:\folder2`

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do if not exist "c:\folder2\%%a" copy "%%a" c:\folder2
```

*Quotes added to cover possible issues identified by @dbenham*

Comment: +1, But your IF NOT EXIST target should be enclosed in quotes to guard against spaces and special characters.

Comment: @dbenham, that should be better. I think I spent *way* too much time with 8.3 filenames

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to extend Sean's answer to copy from folder1 instead of current directory. I've also added quotes around the paths so that spaces and special characters like `&` do not break the code.

```
@echo off
for %%F in ("c:\folder1\*.txt") do if not exist "c:\folder2\%~nxF" copy "%%F" "c:\folder2"
```

You don't even need a batch file. You can simply run the FOR command from the command line if you change all the double percents to single percents.

I also like the shf301 suggestion, though there are so many ROBOCOPY options that it can get confusing until you get used to it. I believe you want the following:

```
robocopy /xn /xo "c:\folder1" "c:\folder2" *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed dbenham